# How to enable Hardware Acceleration on ICS, but disable in Gingerbread?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, hardware-acceleration, android-2.3-gingerbread

I want my app to be hw accelerated in ICS, but support of 2.3.3 is still needed too. Can I enable HW acceleration for ICS only? Or I can only drop 2.3.3 support?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hardware acceleration was not added until 3.0. This is not an issue.

ref: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Comment: I know that there was no HWA in 2.3.3, the question is about how to enable it in ICS.

Comment: Use android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in your application element, as documented.

Comment: Would including the above attribute cause a problem for Android < 3.0? i.e. any exception would be thrown for an unrecognised attribute?

Comment: Nope. We use it in all of our application.

Answer (score 3):

on ICS (android 4+) ,GPU acceleration is enabled by default and can be disabled in the manifest.

up to gingerbread, including,  (up to android 2.3.x) , it's disabled since it's not available at all.

on honeycomb (android 3.x) , it's disabled by default , but can be enabled in the manifest.

Answer (score 3):

There is something else here.

I enabled hardware acceleration for one of my games and it worked fine for ICS, but when I uploaded into the market I got many reports saying that the game became barely playable.

I contacted one of those users and I provided him another version just with hw acceleration turned off. He claimed that it worked better, and he was using gingerbread.

According to the official documentation, enabling hardware acceleration does not have any impact on gingerbread. However my experience is that it has.

Also, the official documentation claims that if you don't declare it and your target is ICS, it is enabled by default. However, when I explicitly turned it on I saw a clear improvement on the animations, swiping and scrolling.

So, the official documentation is not correct and there is a reason to manually disable / enable hardware acceleration for some versions.

I will be disabling hw acceleration in the manifest and using the following code.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=11) {
   getWindow().setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
}
```

I'll let you know if this solves my problems, I hope so.

Edit: It worked fine and I stopped having complains from the users.

Comment: Yes, it will enable it for Honeycomb up. You have to disable it globally on the manifest, this overrides it on runtime.